# Generating bit sequence containing every possible of length 1...n

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Generating sequence containing every possible bit sequence of lengths from $1$ to $n$ is trivial - just generate every possible sequence of length $n$.

But how do you generate the *shortest* sequence containing every possible bit subsequence of lengths from $1$ to $n$ (using the fact that subsequences may partially overlap)?

What complexity class does that problem belong to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a sequence (for arbitrary $k$-ary encodings) is known as a [De Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). For the case of the binary encodings, the De Bruijn sequence has length $2^n$. As the output is exponential, this problem is clearly not in $P$, but it lies in $EXP$, as it can be constructed via a Hamiltonian path along the De Bruijn graph (see [also here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction))